# Prevent a function or a file from being run with nose?

Tags: python, testing, nose

Nose will automatically run any function it finds in the project starting with `test_*`. So, for example, if there is a function called:

```
"""
test_server_setup.py
sets up a pristine database to use for testing.
DO NOT RUN ON PROD
"""

def test_server_init():
    drop_all_tables()
```

...then nose will run it when you run the command `nosetests` from the root of the project. Is my only option to rename this function, or is there another way I can change the file so that nose ignores it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[nottest](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/testing_tools.html#nose.tools.nottest) decorator is exactly what you need:

> nose.tools.nottest(func)
>
> Decorator to mark a function or method as not
>   a test

```
from nose.tools import nottest

@nottest
def test_server_init():
    drop_all_tables()
```

To exclude a file or a directory from being picked up by the nose test discovery, see:

- [Excluding directory, module in python nosetest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24263365/excluding-directory-module-in-python-nosetest)

Comment: This does not answer the post's title "prevent a python file from being run with nose"... rather you show how to prevent a function.

Comment: @nmz787 good point, updated both the question title and the answer. Thanks.

Comment: `nottest` works MUCH better than the now-broken `skip` decorator! (in that I can still explicitly run a class/method that is specified as `nottest`, but that class/method will not be run automatically by nose) Thanks!