# Excluding directory, module in python nosetest

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, nose

We use nose to discover tests and run them. All the tests are written in `TestCase` compatible way so any test runner can run the. Problem is we have some directories which doesn't have any test. But test runner continue to discover test from there. If one of those directory has lot of files its stuck.  So how can I exclude that directory?

Currently I am executing

```
nosetests --processes=10 --verbosity 2
```

But there is a directory called `scripts` which takes ages to discover tests from it. So I want to exclude it.  I tried

```
nosetests --processes=10 --verbosity 2 --exclude='^scripts$'
```

But no luck.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a [`nose-exclude`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose-exclude) plugin specifically for the task:

> nose-exclude is a Nose plugin that allows you to easily specify
>   directories to be excluded from testing.

Among other features, it introduces a new command-line argument called `exclude-dir`:

```
nosetests --processes=10 --verbosity 2 --exclude-dir=/path/to/scripts
```

Instead of passing a command-line argument, you can also set `NOSE_EXCLUDE_DIRS` environment variable, or set `exclude-dir` configuration key in [`.noserc` or `nose.cfg` files](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#configuration).

Comment: So there is not direct way to do these, hence the plugin?

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im I'm afraid plugin is the best option here. `--exclude` nose argument is not applied to directories. I've personally used the plugin and it did the job for me.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im one more thing that I will include into the answer if it works for you. Add `__test__ = False` to the `__init__` of `scripts` package. (if `scripts` is a package, of course). Let me know if it works for you or not. Thanks.

Comment: For **Django** I had to do `--exclude-dir=/path/to/project/app/tests`  - This is the actual *directory* of the tests that I wanted to exclude.  Not a parent directory above it.

Answer (score 11):

You can also use the `--ignore-files` argument to exclude specific files. Since this is using regular expressions, you can name your files inside your `scripts/` folder to begin with a specific prefix that you can then use to match in a regex.

```
# Exclude just one test file
nosetests your_package --ignore-files="tests_to_exclude\.py" -v
# Exclude all python scripts beginning with `testskip_`
nosetests your_package --ignore-files="testskip_.+\.py" -v
```

See: [Nose documentation](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html).

Comment: `nosetests -s -v -x * --ignore-files="Test1\.py" --ignore-files="Test2\.py"` 
This is what am trying, But not worked.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps not what the OP asked for, but I found this tidbit from the nose docs useful to exclude a file from consideration:

> If an object defines a `__test__` attribute that does not evaluate to True, that object will not be collected, nor will any objects it contains.

Comment: This seems to be the only acceptable answer now with `nose2`; sadly this doesn't work when running under python 2 and you're trying to get it to skip a python 3 source file that it can't even parse/compile to get that far...