# nosetests skip certain tests in python with multiple tests

Tags: shell, command-line, build, pipeline, nose

I want to skip or exclude some certain tests from the build or the pipeline.

I am running `nosetests -s -v *` which runs all the tests under some specific folder.

Suppose there are about `30 tests` and out of the `5` I want to skip- To do that I am trying

```
nosetests -s -v * --exclude-test test_sometest.py test_somemoretest.py
```

or

```
nosetests -s -v * -- test_sometest.py test_somemoretest.py
```

but both of them not work for me.

[I am referring from here](https://pypi.org/project/nose-exclude/)

```
#!/bin/sh

cd tests/engine_tests/measures

nosetests -s -v * --exclude-test test_sometest1.py test_somemoretest2.py test_sometest3.py test_somemoretest4.py
```

**Any help would be great!!**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excluding directory, module in python nosetest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24263365/excluding-directory-module-in-python-nosetest)

Comment: Not working. Any Help !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
python -m pytest --cache-clear -v -x -r a --junit-xml=tests/engine_tests --junit-prefix=measure_tests *.py --deselect Test1\.py --deselect Test2\.py --deselect Test3\.py --deselect Test4\.py
```

I tried this and it worked for me. Before that You need to install `pytest`

```
pip install pytest
```

Documentation will be find by typing
`pytest --help` under terminal

or somewhere [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/contents.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add this parameter to your command:
 `--ignore-files="tests_to_exclude\.py"`

Comment: how do i add multiple

Comment: With this do you mean!!!
`nosetests -s -v * --ignore-files="test1.py", "test2.py", "test3.py"`

Comment: Try to escape the `.`

Comment: detailed, please!

Comment: Run `nosetests -s -v * --ignore-files="test1\.py"` and check it doesn't run test1.py

Comment: `nosetests -s -v -x * --ignore-files="Test1\.py"` This is what am trying, But not worked.